# Perl code, defining arguments

Tags: perl, arguments

I have a perl code, but whenever I run it, I can't seem to figure out how to define the first and second argument. Here is the code, help much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Crypt::PBKDF2;

if (@ARGV < 2) {   
print "[!] Error: please specify hash (first argument) and salt (second argument)\n";
exit (1); 
} 
my $match = pack ("H*", $ARGV[0]); # TODO: check if it is of length 40 
my $salt  = pack ("H*", $ARGV[1]); # of length 8? 
my $iter  = 1000; 
my $pbkdf2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new (hash_class => 'HMACSHA1', iterations => $iter);
my $num;
for ($num = 0; $num < 10000; $num++) {
   my $pass = sprintf ("%04d", $num);
   my $hash = $pbkdf2->PBKDF2 ($salt, $pass);
   if ($match eq $hash) {
      printf ("%s:%s:%s:%s\n", unpack ("H*", $hash), unpack ("H*", $salt), $iter, $pass);
      exit (0);
   }
}
exit (1);
```

Comment: "Defining an argument" doesn't make any sense. Are you asking how provide/specify the arguments? `script 8267549af37a... 384a6dd8f900....`

Comment: I mean, I know what numbers I would like to use for the first and second argument. I just do not know how to put them in. And thanks for the help.

Comment: @NinjaBanana define the arguments to what?

Answer (score 2):

if you're refering to these 2 arguments

```
my $match = pack ("H*", $ARGV[0]); # TODO: check if it is of length 40 
my $salt  = pack ("H*", $ARGV[1]); # of length 8?
```

They are defined in the command line.

Assuming your script file is script.pl
In the command line, you need to run

```
perl script.pl <match> <salt>
```

@ARGV is the array containing the command line arguments in Perl

Answer (score 0):

All of Perl's special variables are defined in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), which says the following..

> **@ARGV**
>
> The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended for the script.

If you have suggestions on how that can be made clearer, I'd love to hear them :-)